# Listen audio from many microphones

Tags: c#, audio, naudio, wave

I want to write a program which can get audio from many (say 30) microphones. I can change connected mic. and can listen to the selected mic. I googled and confused about perfect API. Is `Wave` enough for me? `NAudio` is there also and may be many. But which is best for me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From comparisons I've done multi-tracking with Live I'd say ASIO has superior performance.

Comment: ASIO is definitely the way forward, but bear in mind you can only have one ASIO device active at a time (without resorting to additional software that tries to combine multiple soundcards into one), so you'd need an audio interface with a lot of inputs for 30 microphones. NAudio does support ASIO, but I've never tested it with such a large number of inputs, and you might be better off working in C++ to deal with such a lot of realtime audio without dropouts.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to record audio from several microphones at once, you need an API that supports that many channels.

[ASIO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Stream_Input/Output) is a good choice for this.  Sound interfaces with many channels will typically have ASIO drivers.  If you need to combine several traditional sound cards into one device, you can use [ASIO4All](http://www.asio4all.com/), which also tries to sync up the clocks on several cards.

Direct Audio and [Windows Core Audio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370784%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) may also support that many channels, but I haven't worked with them them.

Comment: Direct Audio and Windows Core Audio do NOT support that many channels